# How to compute a modular exponentiation in Crystal?

Tags: math, modulo, crystal-lang, exponentiation

I want to compute `1_299_709 ** 1_300_751 % 104_729` in Crystal.

In Python, the `pow` function allows to pass the modulo as third argument:

```py
❯ python
>>> pow(1_299_709, 1_300_751, 104_729)
90827
```

In Ruby, the same:

```rb
❯ irb
irb(main):001:0> 1_299_709.pow(1_300_751, 104_729)
=> 90827
```

But in Crystal, there seems not to be such a functionality, and naturally, using `**` operators quickly overflows:

```
❯ crystal eval "1_299_709 ** 1_300_751 % 104_729"
Unhandled exception: Arithmetic overflow (OverflowError)
  from /usr/lib/crystal/int.cr:0:9 in '**'
  from /eval:1:1 in '__crystal_main'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/crystal/main.cr:97:5 in 'main_user_code'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/crystal/main.cr:86:7 in 'main'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/crystal/main.cr:106:3 in 'main'
  from __libc_start_main
  from _start
  from ???
```

How to compute a modular exponentiation in Crystal?

---

*Edit:* To clarify, I'm already using `BigInt` but that doesn't work. I removed BigInt from my minimal working example for simplicity.

The following Python code contains the actual numbers from my program:

```py
>>> pow(53583115773616729421957814870755484980404298242901134400501331255090818409243, 28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001977208667916, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663)
75711134420273723792089656449854389054866833762486990555172221523628676983696
```

It executes easily and returns the correct result. Same for Ruby:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> 53583115773616729421957814870755484980404298242901134400501331255090818409243.pow(2894802230932904885589274625217197696331749616641014100986
4396001977208667916, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663)
=> 75711134420273723792089656449854389054866833762486990555172221523628676983696
```

However, Crystal:

```
a = BigInt.new 53583115773616729421957814870755484980404298242901134400501331255090818409243
e = BigInt.new 28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001977208667916
p = BigInt.new 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
y = a ** e % p # overflows with and without BigInt
```

Is resulting in:

```
gmp: overflow in mpz type
Program received and didn't handle signal IOT (6)
```

How to compute such a massive modular exponentiation in Crystal?

---

*Edit:* Filed an issue to make sure it's not a bug: [crystal-lang/crystal#8612](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/8612)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Github issue, this can be easily circumvented by binding `mpz_powm_sec` from `gmp`:

> This is pretty simple:
>   https://carc.in/#/r/89qh
>
> ```
> require "big/big_int"
>
> a = BigInt.new "53583115773616729421957814870755484980404298242901134400501331255090818409243"
> e = BigInt.new "28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001977208667916"
> p = BigInt.new "115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663"
>
> @[Link("gmp")]
> lib LibGMP
>   fun mpz_powm_sec = __gmpz_powm_sec(rop : MPZ*, base : MPZ*, exp : MPZ*, mod : MPZ*)
> end 
>
> #y = a ** e % p
> y = BigInt.new
> LibGMP.mpz_powm_sec(y, a, e, p)
> puts y
>
> # > 75711134420273723792089656449854389054866833762486990555172221523628676983696
> ```